# открытие проекта из Eclipse в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Проект, который был написан и скомпилирован в Eclipse. Работаю в Intellij Idea. Проект клонил с `github`. Все импорты в проекте из Eclipse. Есть ли какая-то утилита или другой способ, чтобы идея могла с ним работать?
 Пример:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTException;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ScrollBar;
```

Comment: Если это проект под Eclipse RCP, то спешу вас огорчить...

Comment: А github открытый? Ссылку дадите?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить зависимости от `org.eclipse.swt` в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Выберите предпочтительный или переместите предпочтительный вверх: -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.maven/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
        <!-- Чтобы использовать отладочную банку, добавьте эту -->
        <classifier>debug</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.wsf/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.86 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kermeta.eclipse/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>${swt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Последние SWT-артефакты для Windows 64 bit:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64

Последние SWT-артефакты для Windows 32 bit:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.maven/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86

Последние SWT-артефакты для Linux 32 bit:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.wsf/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.86

Последние SWT-артефакты для Linux 64 bit:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kermeta.eclipse/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64

Последние SWT-артефакты для MacOS 64 bit:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64

В GitHub:
https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt.binaries

Comment: Если не помогает, то скачайте jar архив и попробуйте подключить зависимость в maven локально. Надеюсь, это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но попробуй вставить вот это в свой `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
   <artifactId>swt</artifactId>
   <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

если не используешь Maven - [jar файл](http://repository.jspresso.org/maven2/org/eclipse/swt/4.6.1/swt-4.6.1.jar)

Comment: не помогло(использую Maven)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам необходимо найти библиотеку под вашу архитектуру, у меня есть проект SWT который я запускаю из idea, кроме основной библиотеки используется масса вспомогательных:

> org.eclipse.jface_3.3.1.M20070910-0800b
>    org.eclipse.jface.text_3.5.0
>    org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.3.100.v20070530
>    org.eclipse.core.commands_3.3.0.I20070605-0010
>    org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.3.0.v20070426
>    org.eclipse.text_3.5.0

Что бы решить возникшие, проблемы совместимости при запуске приложений динамически подключается одна и библиотек(см. ссылку на [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uYCdwVr72G2wPkPax5htJ8SN7BvPAhoF)), для работы самой ide использую `swt-debug.jar`.